# TcpClient getting disposed automatically

Tags: c#, tcp, irc

Using `using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())` Causes the socket to close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is the problem:

```
using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
```

That is automatically closing the stream at the end of the block, which in turn (I believe) closes the socket. The documentation is frankly unclear on this - it says that closing the `TcpClient` *doesn't* close the stream, but it doesn't say for sure about closing the stream...

Comment: Not even sure why that was there anyway -.- but yea what you said was correct. I didnt realize it would close the connection. I have to wait 8 mins to accept the answer though.